# Check for individual row in a group query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, case

```
WITH 
Emp(DName, EName, Role) AS (
     VALUES ('D1','E11', 'Role1'), 
            ('D1','E11', 'Role2'),
            ('D1','E12', 'Role1'), 
            ('D2','E12', 'Role1')
)
```

For each department, fetch the number of individual employees for each role.
The output should be:

```
#_of_Role1_Employees; #_of_Role2_Employees
2; 1
1; 0
```

Comment: +1 for providing ready-to-use testdata

Comment: Can there be duplicate entries per `(DName, EName, Role)`?

Comment: Yes Erwin, there can be duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH 
Emp(DName, EName, Role) AS (
     VALUES ('D1','E11', 'Role1'), 
            ('D1','E11', 'Role2'),
            ('D1','E12', 'Role1'), 
            ('D2','E12', 'Role1')
)
select
    dname "Dname",
    count(role = 'Role1' or null) "Role1",
    count(role = 'Role2' or null) "Role2"
from emp
group by dname
;
 Dname | Role1 | Role2 
-------+-------+-------
 D1    |     2 |     1
 D2    |     1 |     0
```

### Update

This should match the distinct requirement:

```
WITH
Emp(DName, EName, Role) AS (
     VALUES ('D1','E11', 'Role1'),
            ('D1','E11', 'Role2'),
            ('D1','E12', 'Role1'),
            ('D2','E12', 'Role1')
)
select
    dname "Dname",
    count(role = 'Role1' or null) "Role1",
    count(role = 'Role2' or null) "Role2"
from (
    select distinct *
    from emp
) s
group by dname
;
 Dname | Role1 | Role2 
-------+-------+-------
 D1    |     2 |     1
 D2    |     1 |     0
```

Comment: I like how you use `OR NULL` here. :)

Comment: Its very elegant Clodoaldo, however, I missed to mention that duplicates are allowed in the test data. Is there a way to maintain that uniqueness, as a extension of this query?

Answer (score 0):

Within the department Group, each employee row is to be checked for the role, and the distinct employee names are counted.

```
Select COUNT(Distinct(CASE WHEN Role = 'Role1' THEN EName END)) As "#_of_Role1_Employees",
       COUNT(Distinct(CASE WHEN Role = 'Role2' THEN EName END)) As "#_of_Role2_Employees"
from Emp
Group by DName
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that there can be duplicate entries per `(dname, ename, role)` is indication for an over-simplified test case. I suspect the test case should really be:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE emp(dname text, ename text, role text, col1 text);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES
    ('D1','E11', 'Role1', 'foo1')
   ,('D1','E11', 'Role2', 'foo2')
   ,('D1','E12', 'Role1', 'foo3')
   ,('D1','E12', 'Role1', 'foo4')
   ,('D2','E12', 'Role2', 'foo5');
```

Then [@Clodoaldo's (otherwise fine) query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872769/939860) would have to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dname, ename, role
```

instead of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
```

An alternative would be a crosstab query:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
      $x$
      SELECT dname, role, count(DISTINCT ename)::int
      FROM   emp
      GROUP  BY dname, role
      $x$

      ,$y$SELECT DISTINCT role FROM emp ORDER BY 1$y$)
AS ct (dname text, "Role1" text, "Role2" int);
```

You need the [`tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) installed for this. More details for this query in this related answer:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

You have to list all possible roles in the column definition list.